# Developer-tool: Creates large arrays with random-strings for testing-purposes

Tags: javascript, css

I've made this developer-tool for my own use. Perhaps for colleagues too.

Currently I'm thinking about enhancing it. So that different data-types could be chosen.

But before that I like it to be reviewed.

Therefore: Any hints and suggestions concerning algorithm, design, user-interface, whatever welcomed.

```js
var textArea = document.querySelector('textarea');
var exec     = document.querySelector('#exec');
var countOfStrings = document.querySelector('#count-strings');
var linebreak = document.querySelector('#linebreak');
var arrayName = document.querySelector('#array-name');
var maxSelect = document.querySelector('#max');
var separator = document.querySelector('#separator');
// Set of arbitrary words.
var words = [ 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'orange',  
              'yellow', 'white', 'black', 
              'pink', 'cyan', 'crimson',
              'teal', 'lime', 'Alpha', 'Beta', 
              'Gamma', 'Delta', 'North', 
              'East', 'South', 'West' ];
// Create the options of the select-input.
(function() {
  var options = '';
  var currentNumber;
  var i;
  const max = 5;

  for (i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
    currentNumber = Math.pow(10, i);
    options += '<option value="' + currentNumber + '"';

    if (i === 3) {
      options += 'selected="selected" ';
    }

    options += '>' + currentNumber + '</option>\n';
  }

  countOfStrings.innerHTML = options;
})();

/* Creates a stringified array. This array contains 
 *  strings as elements. Each string is made out
 *  of one or multiple random-words.
 *
 * @param { array } words - An array with strings. 
 * @param { number } countOfStrings - Count of strings
 *  within the array.
 * @min { number } [min = 1] - Minimal count of random-words. 
 * @max { number } [max = 1] - Maximal count of random-words. 
 * @param { string } [separator = '-'] - Separator between the
 *  random-words.
 * @param { boolean } [linebreak = false] - Add a linebreak
 *  after each element.
 * @param { string } [arrayName = 'testData'] - The name to the 
 *  returned array.
 * 
 * @returns { string } - Stringified array in case of success. 
 *  Empty string in case of failure.
 */
function getArrayWithTestStrings( words, countOfStrings, min, max, 
                                  separator, linebreak, arrayName ) {
  var ret = [];
  var i;
  // -- Helper-functions -------
  var checkIfNumber = function(num) {
      return typeof num === 'number' && !isNaN(num);
  }

  var getTestStrings = function() {
    var size = Math.floor(min + (Math.random() * (max + 1 - min)));
    var ret = '';
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      ret += words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)] +
        separator;
    }

    return ret.slice(0, ret.length - 1);
  }
  // -- Param-checks ------------
  if ( !words || !Array.isArray(words) || !words.length ) {
    return '';
  }

  if (!countOfStrings || !checkIfNumber(countOfStrings)) {
    return '';
  }
  
  if (!min) {
    min = 1;
  } else if (!checkIfNumber(min)) {
    return '';
  }
  
  if (!max) {
    max = 1;
  } else if (!checkIfNumber(max)) {
    return '';
  }

  arrayName = arrayName || 'testData';
  min = min || 1;
  max = max || 1;
  separator = separator || '-';
  // -- Assemble the array ------- 
  ret = 'var ' + arrayName + ' = [';

  for (i = 0; i < countOfStrings; i++) {
    ret += '"' + getTestStrings() + '",';

    (linebreak && i < countOfStrings - 1) ? 
      ret += '\n' :
      ret += ' ';
  }

  ret = ret.slice(0, ret.length - 2);
  ret += '];';

  return ret;
}

exec.addEventListener('click', function() {
  textArea.textContent =
    getArrayWithTestStrings( words, 
                           parseInt(countOfStrings.value), 
                           1, 
                           parseInt(maxSelect.value), 
                           separator.value, 
                           linebreak.checked, 
                           arrayName.value );
  textArea.select();
});

// -- From here on everything is just an 
//  usage-example! ---------------------

function transferString ( someString ) {
  var ret = someString.replace(/-/g, '_'); 
  return ret.toUpperCase();
}
// Real testing is done with much larger arrays.
var firstParam = ["pink-cyan-pink-crimson",
"North-orange-crimson-black-Beta-yellow",
"Delta-Beta-Alpha-blue-red-Alpha",
"Beta-Delta-North-Beta-cyan-yellow",
"white-Beta-black",
"teal-Gamma-North-pink",
"blue",
"Beta-Delta-lime-Beta-orange",
"orange-orange-cyan-cyan",
"South-white-South"];

var startDate = Date.now();

firstParam.forEach(function(item, i) {
  item = transferString(item);

  if (/-|[a-z]/.test(item)) {
    console.error('Test %s failed.', i);
    console.error(item);
  } else {
   console.log('Test %s succeeded.', i);
    console.log(item);
  }
});

console.log( 'Time needed to process the array: %s ms', 
          Date.now() - startDate );
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #f0f0f0; }

.wrap {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 2% auto; }

.input-group label {
  display: inline-block; }

.input-group {
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around; }

.input-group-part {
  width: 45%; }

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 80px; }

.input-group button {
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 5px 5px; }

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .input-group {
    display: block; }

  .input-group-part {
    width: 100%; }

  .input-group-part:first-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 4%; }

  .input-group label {
    width: 45%; }

  #exec {
    margin-left: 47%; } }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="input-group">
    <textarea></textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-part">
      <label for="array-name">Name of array: </label>
      <input type="text" id="array-name" value="testData" />
    </div>
    <div class="input-group-part">
      <label for="separator">Word-Separator: </label>
      <input type="text" id="separator" size="5" value="-" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-part">
      <label for="count-strings">Count of strings: </label>
      <select id="count-strings" ></select>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group-part">
      <label for="max">Max. parts within string: </label>
      <select id="max">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option selected="selected">5</option>
        <option>6</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-part">
      <label for="linebreak">Add a linebreak: </label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="linebreak" />
    </div>
    <div class="input-group-part">
      <button id="exec" >Execute</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help or advice is appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML Textarea element is quite slow with *very* large amounts of text so you might want to use a simple yet advanced editor like CodeMirror. Even with syntax highlight enabled it's much faster than the native textarea control in the abovementioned case.

Might be useful to auto-copy the result to clipboard - add a `[x] auto copy to clipboard` checkbox, for example.

Showing a length of the code in characters might be useful.

`<input type="search">` would automatically remember past used values in autocomplete.

The log pane on the bottom doesn't seem to be meaningful. And if it is, just showing successfully completed tests in green(-ish) color or using a green mark would be much more obvious.